# How to implement this kind of input design using MUI v5?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[image]

I didn't find any way to implement this kind of design

the [outlined input in MUI](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/#basic-textfield) places the label on the top border, but I want it to be inside the border

Answer (score 0):

You can use MUI `TextField` variant `filled` and change its background or other properties to your needs using the `InputProps`.

```
import * as React from "react";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";

const options = [
  {
    value: "option1",
    label: "option1"
  },
  {
    value: "option2",
    label: "option2"
  },
  {
    value: "option3",
    label: "option3"
  },
  {
    value: "option4",
    label: "option4"
  }
];

export default function SelectTextFields() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("");

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <TextField
      InputProps={{
        style: {
          width: "200px",
          backgroundColor: "#fff",
          border: "2px solid gray",
          borderRadius: "20px"
        },
        disableUnderline: true
      }}
      id="filled-select-currency"
      select
      label="Select"
      value={value}
      onChange={handleChange}
      variant="filled"
    >
      {options.map((option) => (
        <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
          {option.label}
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
    </TextField>
  );
}
```

Output: unselect and select
[image]

Comment: Is there any easy way to handle the border color for hovered, disabled, error states?
and clearly the label is not centered inside the border area :(

Comment: For validation you can use error prop. The error prop toggles the error state. And for lable work around you can add default option. `const [value, setValue] = React.useState("option1");`